# Excel , if the SEARCH function returns an array ,why sometimes it didn't show "#VALUE!"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aTomy | #VALUE! |  |
| aJerryy | #VALUE! | Tom |
|  |  | Jerry |

the code of B2 is

```
=SEARCH(C2:C3,A1)
```

I mean , it's the sensible situation.

But when it comes to:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aTomy | 2 | Tom |
| aJerryy | 2 | Jerry |
|  |  |  |

the code of B2 is

```
=SEARCH(C1:C2,A1)
```

`#VALUE!` is gone and it shows something. It's a result of `=SEARCH(C1,A1)`, but I didn't type it! what I type is `=SEARCH(C1:C2,A1)`, it should be `#VALUE!`. It was still an array!

It's not a big problem because it doesn't affect the result of `ISNUMBER`and`SUMPRODUCT`. But I am curious about what happened in this case, because I can't find any sensible reason.

My version is Microsoft Office Excel 2016.

Answer (score 0):

The second works because it is in the same row. The Search returns an array and then it tries to match it up of Numbers and Errors(`#N/A`)

Instead wrap in INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(SEARCH($C$2:$C$3,A1),MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$3,A1)),0))
```

With 2016, you may need to confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode, then copy down.

[image]